# How to launch executable file from website with php?

Tags: php, shell, com, sh, php-extension

I want to launch (not install) an .apk/.bat/sh files when clicked on the website in the Without warning or downloading. I found that codes in php offical website:

```
<?php $WshShell = new COM("/home/user/Desktop/test.sh /C");
$oExec = $WshShell-\>Run("cmd /C dir /S %windir%", 0, false);
?\>
```

Im running from Linux in VSCodiumBut i have a dot com problem:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/user/Desktop/test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/user/Desktop/test.php on line 6

I tried to add the extension and add the code in php.ini it got worse i guess, now it gives me that error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_com_dotnet.dll' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_com_dotnet.dll (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_com_dotnet.dll: invalid ELF header), /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_com_dotnet.dll.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_com_dotnet.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Im not sure did i add the code right and the file with correct location.

Comment: What operating system are you running PHP on? There seems to be some confusion between Windows and Linux here (you have a linux-like folder path, but then seem to be trying to run cmd.exe). And can you run an apk file on either of those? Perhaps with an emulator? I don't know. Also, anything you run via PHP will run on the webserver, not on the end user's local machine. Not sure if that's your intention or not, it wasn't clear.

Comment: Do you want the file to be run on the server hosting the backend - or on the client machine clicking the link? The later is hopefully NOT possible without confirmation in ANY way :P

Comment: @dognose its educational purposes only :) You know what im looking for. I have to upload it to my website. When the client click the website its gotta be launched for client. I guess thats the correct definition. I dont know how to tell any else. Bind shell maybe ? *Its all in ethic.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it cannot make the client do anything other than what is sent inside of an HTTP response, and no browser on earth is going to launch an untrusted executable without a warning and user confirmation.

Comment: Check Microsoft ClickOnce. It's a deployment method for .net based code that can be executed right away without installing it first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2022

Comment: In ngrok link you can click easily (you were now its warning himself) the professional and real thing is embed that in a website. Exp. google and many websites are even before the page is loading, locating your place and showing your location or up to your location results. And how ngrok executing/running that shell system from a website ?

Comment: The location data you see on Web pages comes from an API built into your browser. It does not require a shell command. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API . At some point you, as the user, will have given your consent to this, the first time a website requested your browser to give the information.

Comment: And what about ngrok ?

Comment: What about it? I don't understand your point. Why do you think ngrok is relevant to your question? ngrok is essentially just a reverse proxy combined with some firewall and load balancing services. It cannot execute commands on the end user's machine, and it cannot ascertain their location.

Comment: `I am running from Linux`...so then why are you trying to install the [PHP COM library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php)? As the documentation says, COM is Windows-only technology. And `cmd` is only a Windows command. And `.dll` files are Windows only. And even in Windows, you wouldn't need COM just to run a bat file or shell script. Meanwhile in PHP, there is the cross-platform [`shell_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) (and similar functions) which can execute any command-line script on the host server. It still cannot execute on the user's machine tho

Comment: I was getting involve to achieve it. Now i can tell more properly what is my goal. Im trying to reverse shell a computer/mobile device. When i see the shell in localhost/ and clicked it, the shell is launching. But i want to automaticly launch from index.php. I found something about apk, but its requesting to allow. The better is not need permission but it alerting you. And again you need to click it from localhost/directory not auto launching

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse shell"? Please make it clearer

Comment: Its the name of it. Its cyber security area. What i did is, add a reverse shell in a php and upload to localhost. Its normally vuln. bug of website. You launch outside of the website and you can hack the website by this. Im trying to do the reverse. Launch the listener from website to listen and get control/eavesdrop/remote the client. Lets say youtube and your smartphone listening you (from microphone -because you didnt search that words) and recommending you the websites and songs in youtube right ?

Comment: OK I read about it and I understand now. But you cannot create a reverse shell without first exploiting some vulnerability in the target machine so that you can run the command to create the shell. From a web application there is no way to run that command on the user's local machine in the first place, except perhaps by carrying out some social engineering attack where you convince the user to download and execute the script which opens the shell connection. You cannot fully automate it. Unlike a webserver you cannot exploit something like sql or xss injection to get the code on there.

Comment: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/what-is-reverse-shell/ has a good explanation and some sample codes, including php.

Comment: P.s. `Lets say youtube and your smartphone listening you (from microphone`...again this specific example does not come from an exploit. It happens because at some time the user gave an application or web page specific permission to use the system's microphone, and agreed to the terms and conditions (even if they didn't really read them!) so that they consented for it to collect such data and use it for advertising. So it is not an example of the process you are proposing to create.

Comment: Ok that's good. If your solution is useful for others then please feel free to post it as an answer below - see also [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Its solved. Appears you cant do without any permission or launch auto from inside of website. And more than that it has to vulnerabilities.